# Can Java be used to make a 2D Bird's eye view style game?

Tags: java, 2d

I've been working on making a video game, and I've had alot of debate between a few languages, Java can be used well for 3D games but. Can Java make 2D bird's eye view games? I'm quiet new to programming so sorry if I seem somewhat ignorant. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can do whatever you want with Java 2D and 3D, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

that's not a question `can Java make a 2d bird's eye game?`. the main quesiton is `does a 2d bird's game created with java meet your needs or not?`. just by looking at cell phones you can easily spot many 2D games using bird's eye camera created with java. ***so it sure can!***

Comment: Well, the people i were talking to didn't do their homework, they told me java can really only be used to make 3D games, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bumpeh They are mis-informed. Also consider that OpenGL can render a "flat 2D view" just fine if the projection is setup to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. (This simple answer is as exciting as the question.)

I used [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) to make a 2D "bird's eye" game in OpenGL. It just requires setting up the perspective correctly. Performance on a laptop (with a proper OpenGL 1.6+ dedicated video card ;-) was more than adequate for a large number of objects and particles.

However, LWJGL is a low-level OpenGL/basic-IO wrapper targeted for games and is the "hard way". There are other Java game libraries (some are just 2D like [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/)) to make writing a game easier. According to [list of game engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) this also includes Jake2, Jogre, and Java Monkey Engine (3D, but see above).

If one felt like being .. silly .. the Java 2D API could be used directly (there are cases when it will try to use hardware acceleration but there are also gotchas). I do not do any JME programming, but I would suspect there are also frameworks for it.

And remember -- a "bird's eye view" is simply the chosen projection/rendering for a given model.

Happy coding.